# Js files don't work in loaded content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

tabs.js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#activites').click(function(){
        $('#target').load('activites.php');
    })

    $('#jobs').click(function(){
        $('#target').load('jobs.php');
    })

   $('#employees').click(function(){
      $('#target').load('employees.php');
   })
})
```

index  (current page):

```
<!-- page content -->
<div id="target">&nbsp;</div>
<!-- page content end-->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Parsley -->
<script src="vendors/parsleyjs/dist/parsley.min.js"></script>
<!-- Custom Theme Scripts -->
<script src="build/js/custom.min.js"></script>
```

these Js files don't get applied to any of these files loaded

```
activites.php
jobs.php
employees.php
```

Comment: Is the URL correct? What errors are shown in the developer console of your browser?

Comment: What do you mean with "applied"? Whats in the pages and what should be "applied" and when?

Comment: semicolons `;` are optional but you should try to always add it as is a good practice

Comment: Do you mean to say that dynamically generated content doesn't trigger event handlers initialized on page load? This is a common mistake, and you should use [delegated event handling](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to address this issue.

Comment: Where are your dom elements with the ids that you are binding to?

Comment: Can you edit in the errors you're getting? Not sure this needs to be tagged jQuery too.

Comment: the problem is the loaded page ex. activites.php has forms elements. and these forms need js plugin i added in index.php. before the end of body tag now the plugin i added to index.php don't do any affect on the loaded content from activites.php i don't know how to get it work

Comment: I think it's near what Mr Patrick issue said i will try to understand the delegated event handling

Comment: this is what i get in the console:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isValid' of undefined
    at a (custom.min.js:1)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (custom.min.js:1)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I have to do to get the js files works with loaded page is not add it in the main page but add it in the loaded page

load.php content

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Managment Level</label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <select id="management_lvl" class="form-control" required>
            <option value="">Choose option</option>
            <option value="top">Top</option>
            <option value="middle">Middle</option>
            <option value="low">Low</option>
            <option value="no_skilled">No- Skilled</option>
            <option value="no_semi_skilled">No- Semi Skilled </option>
            <option value="no_non_skilled">No- Non Skilled </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     $.getScript("build/js/custom.min.js");
     $.getScript("vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js");
     $.getScript("vendors/parsleyjs/dist/parsley.min.js");
     $.getScript("vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js");
     $.getScript("vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js");
 </script>
```

if you load these js files on the main page it doesn't work on the page loaded